# Why does the class that extends the abstract class must have main method

Tags: java

am trying to access the add function of the class that extended the abstract class which has the abstract add method. please have a look at the below code

```
         public abstract class Ar {
       abstract int add(int a, int b);
      }


      public class Adder extends Ar {

     int add(int a,int b){
    return a+b;
     }

   /*public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        Adder a = new Adder();

      }*/
   } 

public class Sol {

    static void main(String atgs[])
   {
      Adder aa = new Adder();
      System.out.println(aa.getClass().getSuperclass().getSimpleName());
      System.out.println(aa.add(10, 10));
}
}
```

When i comment the main method declaration in the Adder class, am getting the error "Error: Main method not found in class", but why do i need main method in Adder class?

Even when i un-comment the main method, am not getting the blank output.

Comment: are the 3 classes in the same file

Comment: You don't. You're trying to execute `Adder`, try running `Sol`.

Comment: No, its not compulsory to define a main method in a class that extends an Abstract class. There might be some other issues.

Comment: ALso, it may be possible that you are trying to execute Adder. You must have to execute Sol.

Comment: You've got 72 rep points -- and so surely you know how to post well formatted code by now, right? You also know that if code is well formatted, it is more easily understood, right?

Comment: @Ashish, Am actually executing the Sol class, which says to define main method in Adder class!

Comment: please use public in front of your "static void main(String atgs[])", as if you donn't use public this will make default.And not be called by JVM

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args)` is the standard main signature which the compiler looks for.

Comment: @prabhakarReddyG have u tried after using public in front of main

Comment: @Ashish, Yeah, it worked fine now!!!! thanks dude.

Comment: @AshishAni - Actually, the >>compiler<< doesn't look for it.  The compiler doesn't care if there is a `main` method at all.  It is the `java` command that looks for the `main` method.

Answer (score 2):

`static void main(String atgs[])` main has to be `public` and since all your classes have `public`modifier  make sure your classes are in seperate files

Answer (score 0):

main() in Sol class has to be public otherwise compiler will not able to get the main() to start execution. Moreover if you uncomment the main() in Adder class, then it will works but will not give any output as it is not having any System.out.println() statement.

You could try this

```
abstract class Ar {
       abstract int add(int a, int b);
      }


class Adder extends Ar {

     int add(int a,int b){
    return a+b;
     }

   public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        Adder a = new Adder();

      }
   } 

class Sol {

    public static void main(String atgs[])
   {
      Adder aa = new Adder();
      System.out.println(aa.getClass().getSuperclass().getSimpleName());
      System.out.println(aa.add(10, 10));
}
}
```

Here output will depend on execution of class file

For java Sol 
output - 
Ar
20

For java Adder , ouput will be blank.